# Couldn't calculate prime numbers within a range

Tags: r

```
for (i in 2:100 )
{
  count <- 0
  for (j in i )

        if( (i %% j  ) == 0 )
            count <- count + 1

    if(count == 2 )  
      print(i)  
}
```

I am trying to print print prime numbers in R. Could any one help me  to resolve

Comment: `isPrime<-Vectorize(function(n)if(n>1){if(n<4) TRUE else all(n%%seq(2,floor(sqrt(n)))!=0)}); sum(isPrime(2:100))`

Comment: My answer below can be used for your example and all  other ranges of positive integers.  Best wishes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us look at your code and show what went wrong. It's the inner loop that did not loop at all:

```
for (i in 2:100 )
{
  count <- 0
  for (j in 1:i ) # you forgot to provide a vector here

    if( i %% j == 0 )
      count <- count + 1

    if(count == 2)
      print(i)
}
```

The answer above tries to optimise the code some more and is a more efficient solution. For example does it only test odd numbers because even ones clearly aren't prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The below code creates the function `prime_numbers` which returns prime numbers up to an inputted number.

```
prime_numbers <- function(n) {
if (n >= 2) {
 x = seq(2, n)
 prime_nums = c()
 for (i in seq(2, n)) {
   if (any(x == i)) {
     prime_nums = c(prime_nums, i)
     x = c(x[(x %% i) != 0], i)
     }
   }
 return(prime_nums)
 }
 else {
   stop("Input number should be at least 2.")
 }
} 
## return the answer to your question
prime_numbers(100)
```

If you wanted the range `3:100`, after running the above code you could run something like this:

```
a<-prime_numbers(100)
a[a>3]
```

I hope this helps!